# Install Commands in Linux (useradd,ifconfig)

Tags: linux, unix, ubuntu, redhat

In my filesystem there is no  "useradd" command. How can I install that?
I tried with `$sudo yum install useradd`, but it shows no package useradd available and shows nothing to do.
If commands are under packages, how to know which command is in which package?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [yum whatprovides](http://yum.baseurl.org/wiki/YumCommands) to get the name of the package that contains a certain file. You can either specify the full path to a file or you can use wildcards. For example, type

```
sudo yum whatprovides \*useradd
```

to find the package that provides useradd.

To give you an example output: The output of  `yum provides \*bin/ls` would be

```
coreutils-6.12-17.fc10.i386 : The GNU core utilities: a set of tools commonly
                            : used in shell scripts
Matched from:
Filename    : /bin/ls
```

There you can see that the corresponding package is **coreutils**, i.e. you could install it via `sudo yum install coreutils`, if you need it.

**Edit:** Just a note on useradd: You usually need to be root or have sudo privileges to add a new user. So just invoking useradd as "normal" user might fail and even not find the file, while doing the same as root works as expected.

Comment: It shows in which path useradd is but how to install it

Comment: after find the package and installed it but it shows same like setting up install process then nothing to do

Comment: The package is already installed but the command is not there what to do guys plz help?

Comment: If the package is already installed, you can try to reinstall the package. Use `yum reinstall packagename` to do that.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like `useradd` is provided by the `shadow-utils` package.